# Evaluating a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Is it possible to find real $x$, $y$, and $s$, with $s \in (0,1)$, such that
$$\cos\left(\frac{x - y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x + y}{2}\right)\cos\left(sx + (1 - s)y\right)$$
equals $1$?

The thing I see is that $\cos(\frac{x - y}{2})\sin(\frac{x + y}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}(\sin(x) + \sin(y))$ but I don't what else to do! 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: **Hint**: Note that $\sin(x)+\sin(y)\le2$ and that $\cos(sx+(1-s)y)\le1$. Therefore we need the maximum value of each sine.

Comment: Even before applying the product formula it was clear
that each factor is in $[-1,+1]$ and thus they all must equal $\pm 1$.

Comment: $s$ is listed twice in the OP. $\;$

Comment: That actually makes sense, but it would be clearer if the text
implied between the two $s$'s were spelled out:
"...to find real $x,y,s$ such that $s \in (0,1)$"
[or "....such that $0<s<1$"] etc.  Without the repetition
it would say that $x$ and $y$ must also be in the interval $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
\begin{align*}
x=&\,\frac{9\pi}{2},\\y=&\,\frac{\pi}{2},\\s=&\,\frac{3}{8}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

The only way this can be true is if:
$$x-y = 2n\pi,\ \ x+y=(2m+1)\pi,\ \ sx+(1-s)y=k\pi$$
Where $n,m,k\in\mathbb{Z}$. This leads to:
$$x = (1 + 2 m + 2 n) \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$y = (1 + 2 m - 2 n) \frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$s = (-1 + 2 k - 2 m + 2 n)\frac{1}{4n}$$
So, choose any integer $n,m,k$ you want. You'll get triple_sec's answer if you use $n=m=k=2$.

Comment: It's not necessary that $s=1/2$. See my answer below.

Comment: @triple_sec - my bad, fixed.

Comment: This needs more refinement. For example, if $n=1$ and $m=k=0$, then the result is $-1$, not $1$. Observe that, according to your formulation, $(x-y)/2=n\pi$, so that $\cos((x-y)/2)\in\{-1,1\}$. This should be matched with a value of $-1$ of exactly one of the two other expressions. Finally, make sure that $s\in(0,1)$.